# How to access next row after dataframe ix?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to access next row of entry of dataframe at `index01`:
ex:

next row of `df.ix[index01]`?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use [index.get_loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) and keep in mind that `ix` is deprecated:

```
df.iloc[df.index.get_loc(index01) + 1]
```

This assumes `index01` is the label. If that's the position you can just use `df.iloc[index01 + 1]` of course.